Use Leaflet tile call with TomTom custom map style
I'm using a leaflet map with the tile layout from TomTom using this url
https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?tileSize=512&view=Unified&language=NGT&key=?

and taken from this documentation https://developer.tomtom.com/map-display-api/documentation/raster/map-tile
I created a custom style with the MapMaker and want to use it with Leaflet. However if I check the publish map maker documentation here https://developer.tomtom.com/map-maker/documentation/cloud-styles/using-style-in-the-application I can't find anything. This describes only how to use it directly with the style import but this is not working with Leaflet.
Already tried fiddling around with the api url from above but couldn't find a working solution.
Is this possible?

With raster maps you can only use prerendered styles.
If you want to use custom style, then you need to use a Vector tile extension for Leaflet.
